# stripe webhook gives blank page cant see page

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i want to send a email and insert data to database after the stripe webhook got the payment true. but when the payment comes true you can't see the succes message on the page that i have included in the succes page. The page is full blank.
And when i insert my sendemail() function it don't want to insert the data & send the email it says $email = $_get['email'] not defined but i included my fetch.php i get all the data from the url:
cadeau.php?bon=voetbehandeling&client_secret=src_client_secret_E745XOwwOtHh45umH8WM6iGA&email=test%40gmail.com&id=581584884891450162oaana&livemode=false&source=src_1GPU9uGzJT0kic6B2AxtPOAh

**script.js**

```
  var idealBank = elements.create('idealBank', options);

// Add an instance of the idealBank Element into
// the `ideal-bank-element` <div>.
idealBank.mount('#ideal-bank-element');
idealBank.on('change', function(event) {
  var bank = event.value;
  // Perform any additional logic here...

});
// Create a source or display an error when the form is submitted.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var randNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2 + "" + new Date().getTime() +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 2 + (Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '').substr(0, 5));
  var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
  var sourceData = {
    type: 'ideal',
    amount: price,
    currency: 'eur',
    statement_descriptor: 'U heeft een tegoedbon gekocht = ' + bon,
    owner: {
      name: document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value,
      email: document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value,
    },
    // Specify the URL to which the customer should be redirected
    // after paying.
    redirect: {
      return_url: 'https://www.pedicurepraktijkpapendrecht.nl/stripe/cadeau.php' + '?email=' + email + '&id=' + randNo + '&bon=' + bon,

    },
  };

  // Call `stripe.createSource` with the idealBank Element and
  // additional options.
  stripe.createSource(idealBank, sourceData).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('error-message');
      errorElement.textContent = error.message;
    } else {
      // Redirect the customer to the authorization URL.
      stripeSourceHandler(result.source);
    }
  });
});


function stripeSourceHandler(source) {
  // Redirect the customer to the authorization URL.
  document.location.href = source.redirect.url;
}
```

**succes page**

```
    ?php
include('./webhook.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Email versturen naar uw email!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-row">
        <h1>Bedankt voor het kopen van een tegoedbon!</h1>
        <p>Uw tegoedbon word gestuurd naar uw email!</p>
        <div class="flex">
            <a href="https://www.pedicurepraktijkpapendrecht.nl/"
                class="btn text-center margin-right max-width">Naar de
                website</a>
            <a href="checkout.php" class="btn text-center margin-right max-width">Nog een tegoedbon kopen?</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**webhook.php**

```
    require('./vendor/autoload.php');
$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_4lLBwyPL7TG2zi4Azl8Q5KBggzOZUqet';


$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

if ($event->type == "source.chargeable") {
    $intent = $event->data->object;
    printf("Succeeded: %s", $intent->id);
    http_response_code(200);
    exit();
} elseif ($event->type == "source.failed") {
    $intent = $event->data->object;
    $error_message = $intent->last_payment_error ? $intent->last_payment_error->message : "";
    printf("Failed: %s, %s", $intent->id, $error_message);
    http_response_code(200);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about what you're trying to do? The user should never see the webhook page. Your Webhook endpoint is a URL that is purely for Stripe to send POST requests to, but users never actually see that page. It's unclear what the goal is here.

Comment: sooo i dont have to include the webhook page in my success page?

Comment: i try to send an email with the succes page when the payment is paid and when the payment failed i want to go to the the checkout page soo they can try again

Comment: You'll want to send the email from your webhook handler. That's part of fulfillment that should be handled in the webhook handler. The webhook page does not redirect to your success page. If payment fails, you can handle that with your client or server code that is confirming payment intent.